# Questions returned by /questions/{ids}/related do not contain link properties

Tags: support, bug, questions, api

The API docs claim that `/questions/{ids}/related` return [question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) objects, but I can't find a `link` property on the returned questions at all.

Is there some sort of workaround to find the link for a question without a separate call to 
`/questions/{ids}`?

Comment: @TimStone I was trying [this](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions/13752517/related), which gives me all related questions, but without the link properties. Not using any filters, no.

Comment: @TimStone I knew I was doing something stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you linked to is for API 2.x, but you're querying 1.1 which doesn't return those exact objects (and is deprecated). [This API 2.1 request](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/13752517/related?site=stackoverflow) will return the results you were expecting:

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/13752517/related?site=stackoverflow
```